# Why are there bright unwanted lights coming out of nowhere in my render?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have no idea why, but this keeps happening to my renders, most of the time, when volumetric lighting is involved, sometimes not. But is there any way to fix it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: could you give more information please ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While images and links are helpful additions, questions should stand on their own. [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post an image or link](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

These are sometimes called fire flies.
This can be eliminated by setting the "clamp indirect"value to 1, found in the "sampling" section in the "render" tab.

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about fireflies, but hidden objects.

Comment: Sorry, miss understood the question then. Still worth a try though, you never know.

Comment: Fireflies are significantly smaller, I would hate to find a firefly that big!

Comment: @Moog maybe it's just a different type of firefly that you haven't seen before https://www.firefly.org/types-of-fireflies.html

Comment: Its possible its a mutation.